# SVG filepath support in HTML: difference between local and remote?

Tags: html, svg, path, ftp, png

```
<img src="./img/pic.png">
<img src="./img/pic.svg">
```

Locally the two lines above work and display two pictures but once deployed remotely (for example, on a ftp) only the png displays (permissions are set to the most permissive for both files).

Any idea?

By the way, it seems any sort on svg cannot be display, I can access to pic using its path but loading in html does not work.

I'm sure this is real stupid.

Comment: I assume you've got the mime type for svg incorrectly set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems weird as SVG support is pretty good on a lot of browsers

http://caniuse.com/#search=svg

This *could* be down to your server, If it's an Apache server you could try adding

```
AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz
AddEncoding gzip svgz
```

to the .htaccess.

Comment: I was really hoping that the .htaccess trick will do but sadly not, really weird.

Comment: Using your `.htaccess` try setting the config to "allow" file-extention `.svg`

Comment: Using your browser's "developer tools", visit the page and have a look at the error message you get in the "network" section -next to that svg file

Comment: @CharlSteynberg actually, at that time I have already investigated a lot using the developer tools whether with Chrome or Firefox, but honestly it seems everything was loaded, no errors whatsoever. 
It seems that now it's working perfectly fine and I'm wondering whether it was just not a caching issue from the browser (I tried to clean it up several times though before posting my comment). I accept this answer cause it is sound to me and has, apparently, solved my issue.